# No new function discovered in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

This is my first semi-professional project in Python.
And I'm in trouble.

Python does not understand the `ch_pass` function and only understands the first function, `create_user`.
This means that when you press button 2, Python executes the second function.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

```
    def start():
    a = input('''
Welcome,
[+] (1) Create new user
[+] (2) Change your password

what do you want to do? : ''')


    if a == 1:
        creat_user()

    elif a == 2:
        ch_pass()

        #do it again
    def again():
        again_v = input('For Menu type (M) for Exit type (E) : ')
        if again_v.upper() == 'M':
            start()
        elif again_v.upper() == 'E':
            print('Good Luck !')
        else:
            again()

    
        #create username and password
    def creat_user():
        user = input('Enter your Username : ')
        Pass = input('Enter your Password : ')
        userpass = subprocess.check_output('net user {} {} /add' . format(user,Pass) , shell=True)
        adm = subprocess.check_output('net localgroup administrators {} /add' . format(user) , shell=True) #give administrator to user
        print('Done !')    

    creat_user()
    again()    
        
        
        #change password        
    def ch_pass():
        u = input('Ok, Enter your Username : ')
        p = input('Now, Enter your new Password : ')
        u_p = subprocess.check_output('net user {} {}' . format(u,p) , shell=True)
        print('Action completed !')

    ch_pass()
    again()

start()
```

Comment: `a` will never equal either 1 or 2 because it's a string.

Comment: your indentation is quite strange, are you sure you have it this way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your functions before their first call, otherwise the interpreter does not know they exist. And you need to cast the `str` to an `int`. Try this:

```
#do it again
def again():
    again_v = input('For Menu type (M) for Exit type (E) : ')
    if again_v.upper() == 'M':
        start()
    elif again_v.upper() == 'E':
        print('Good Luck !')
    else:
        again()

    
#create username and password
def creat_user():
    user = input('Enter your Username : ')
    Pass = input('Enter your Password : ')
    userpass = subprocess.check_output('net user {} {} /add' . format(user,Pass) , shell=True)
    adm = subprocess.check_output('net localgroup administrators {} /add' . format(user) , shell=True) #give administrator to user
    print('Done !')  


#change password        
def ch_pass():
    u = input('Ok, Enter your Username : ')
    p = input('Now, Enter your new Password : ')
    u_p = subprocess.check_output('net user {} {}' . format(u,p) , shell=True)
    print('Action completed !') 


def start():
    a = input('''
Welcome,
[+] (1) Create new user
[+] (2) Change your password

what do you want to do? : ''')
    
    # Add this line
    a = int(a)


    if a == 1:
        creat_user()

    elif a == 2:
        ch_pass()
 

    creat_user()
    again()    

    ch_pass()
    again()

start()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tested this code but this time the function again() is not recognized.

Comment: I had a minor mistake where I used // instead of # for a comment, I fixed it and ran this code and it worked fine for me. Can you copy the exact error message?

Comment: I solved the // problem, but after ran the script, this time Python understood the ch_pass function and it worked properly. The problem was that Python did not understand the again function and did not execute it every time after the end of the ch_pass or create_user functions. So, there wasn't any error.